# Given two different sets, A and B, how many functions there are with domain A and codomain B?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Consider sets $A=\left\{a,\:b,\:c,\:d\right\}$ and $B=\left\{1,\:2,\:3\right\}$. How many functions can be defined with domain $A$ and codomain $B$?

How would guess it is the cardinality of the power set of $A$ x $B$, but I'm lost on this one...

Comment: Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be one such map. Then you have either all points in A landing in just one point in B, or all points in A landing in any 2 points in B, and so on...

Comment: @thedilated No need for cases. For each element of the domain $A$, there are $|B|$ choices for its image, so we get $|B|^{|A|}$ functions total.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is not correct.  There are $3$ choices for $f(a)$, $3$ choices for $f(b)$, and so on.  These choices are completely independent of one another, so there are a total of $3^4 = 81$ functions from $A$ *into* $B$.  But if I correctly understand your question, you want the number of surjections.

So you have to subtract the number of functions that aren't surjections.  There is one way to map a $4$-element set into a $1$-element set and you have three elements to choose from, so there are $3$ functions that map $A$ onto a single element of $B$.

There are $2^4=16$ ways to map a $4$-element set into a $2$-element set, but $2$ of those don't hit both elements, so there are $14$ ways to map a $4$-element set *onto* a $2$-element set.  There are $3$ ways to choose a $2$-element subset of $B$ so there are $42$ functions from $A$ into $B$ that map into exactly $2$ elements of $B$.

Thus, of the $81$ total functions from $A$ into $B$, $45$ of them are **not** surjective.  That means there are $36$ functions from $A$ *onto* $B$.

Comment: Good answer, though [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) does not mean range, so they are not asking about surjections.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not familiar with the term so I guessed that it meant image.